# Paginate a custom array in Cakephp without creating a new model

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, pagination, paging

I have a custom array like this:

```
     array( 
       [0]=>array(
           'user' => array(
              'id' => 1,
              'name' => 'A',
           ) 
       ),
       [2]=>array(
           'user' => array(
              'id' => 2,
              'name' => 'B',
           ) 
       ),
       [3]=>array(
           'user' => array(
              'id' => 3,
              'name' => 'C',
           ) 
       ),
    );
```

I did some research and read on cookbook but could only paginate with a model.
This code gave me the error not finding model user.

```
$this->paginate = array(
     'limit' => 2,
     'order' => array('id' => 'desc')
);
$user = $this->paginate('user');
```

How can i pass the array to cakephp pagination in my controller without having to create a new model?

Comment: Paginating arrays is not supported, you'd have to come up with a solution on your own (or look out for possible existing third party implementations). ps, please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Yes I am creating the pagination on my own, not using cakephp paginator. And btw I am using the latest version cakephp 3.4.0. Thanks